# how to integrate external data source with Cucumber feature file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I have created cucumber feature file. As of now I am giving input from scenario outline with Examples.

But My test data is very huge now. I just want to give input from CSV or EXCEL.

Could you please explain How to achieve this ?

Comment: You can't read the data directly via Gherkin without a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388384/in-cucumber-feature-file-examples-how-to-set-path-for-csv-file), but since you are using Java, you have a full programming language to use for reading Excel or csv wo=ith POI for example.

Comment: yes, thank you form replying , i am trying  to code it on java, is there any existing  library that imports data from excel thank you

Comment: I already said, Apache POI

Answer (score 3):

If you are using cucumber version 5+ you can use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) that will enable external test data with [in-built data providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#in-built-data-providers) and many other features from qaf.
Below is example of test data from CSV usage. You can switch to any available data-provider or you can create custom as well.

```
Feature: my feature    

@dataFile:resources/data/testdata.csv
Scenario: my scenario
...
```